# Exclude items from one list based on second list in Python

Tags: python

I've searched for more than an hour and haven't found exactly the solution to this, but it likely has been asked - any pointers are very welcome.

I have time series data (time, flux) with gaps from the Kepler satellite.  I filled in missing points so I could apply a Fourier high-pass filter.  Now I want to delete the filled points from the filtered data (time, flux_residuals) so I have only the time values that were in the original data.

So as a parallel example, say that my original data and filtered data are:

```
xorig = np.array([1,2,5,6]) 
yorig = (doesn't matter)

xf = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]) 
yf = xf + 10
```

What is a pythonic way to extract the elements in yf where corresponding elements of xf are in xorig?

```
[11,12,15,16]
```

Comment: May be `yf[np.in1d((yf - 10), xorig)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [np.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
print(yf[np.in1d(xf, xorig)])

[11 12 15 16]
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does it!  Much appreciated.